# Remove Space between nested tables

Tags: html, css

I am working on responsive newsletter using HTML, inline css as much as possible and some css also.

I am facing issue in design as i am not able to remove space between first Image and second table after image..

https://codepen.io/KGuide/full/oNXwyEW

```css
 html,
        body {
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
            background: #fff;
        }
        
        /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }
        
        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        
        /* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
        img {
           /* -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; */
         
        }
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
          .primary{
         background: #f5564e;
        }
        .bg_white{
         background: #ffffff;
        }
        .bg_light{
         background: #fafafa;
        }
        .bg_black{
         background: #000000;
        }
        .bg_dark{
         background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        }
        .email-section{
         padding:2.5em;
        }
        
        /*BUTTON*/
        .btn{
         padding: 5px 15px;
         display: inline-block;
        }
        .btn.btn-primary{
         border-radius: 5px;
         background: #f5564e;
         color: #ffffff;
        }
        .btn.btn-white{
         border-radius: 5px;
         background: #ffffff;
         color: #000000;
        }
        .btn.btn-white-outline{
         border-radius: 5px;
         background: transparent;
         border: 1px solid #fff;
         color: #fff;
        }
        
        h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
         font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
         color: #000000;
         margin-top: 0;
        }
        
        body{
         font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
         font-weight: 400;
         font-size: 15px;
         line-height: 1.8;
         color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        }
        
        a{
         color: #f5564e;
        }
        
        table{
        }
        /*LOGO*/
        
        .logo h1{
         margin: 0;
        }
        .logo h1 a{
         color: #000;
         font-size: 20px;
         font-weight: 700;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
        }
        
        .navigation{
         padding: 0;
        }
        .navigation li{
         list-style: none;
         display: inline-block;;
         margin-left: 5px;
         font-size: 12px;
         font-weight: 700;
         text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        .navigation li a{
         color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        }
        
        /*HERO*/
        .hero{
         position: relative;
         z-index: 0;
        }
        .hero .overlay{
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         content: '';
         width: 100%;
         background: #000000;
         z-index: -1;
         opacity: .3;
        }
        .hero .icon{
        }
        .hero .icon a{
         display: block;
         width: 60px;
         margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .hero .text{
         color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
         padding: 0 4em;
        }
        .hero .text h2{
         color: #ffffff;
         font-size: 40px;
         margin-bottom: 0;
         line-height: 1.2;
         font-weight: 900;
        }
        
        
        /*HEADING SECTION*/
        .heading-section{
        }
        .heading-section h2{
         color: #000000;
         font-size: 24px;
         margin-top: 0;
         line-height: 1.4;
         font-weight: 700;
        }
        .heading-section .subheading{
         margin-bottom: 20px !important;
         display: inline-block;
         font-size: 13px;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         letter-spacing: 2px;
         color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
         position: relative;
        }
        .heading-section .subheading::after{
         position: absolute;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: -10px;
         content: '';
         width: 100%;
         height: 2px;
         background: #f5564e;
         margin: 0 auto;
        }
        
        .heading-section-white{
         color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
        }
        .heading-section-white h2{
         font-family: 
         line-height: 1;
         padding-bottom: 0;
        }
        .heading-section-white h2{
         color: #ffffff;
        }
        .heading-section-white .subheading{
         margin-bottom: 0;
         display: inline-block;
         font-size: 13px;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         letter-spacing: 2px;
         color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
        }
        
        
        .icon{
         text-align: center;
        }
        .icon img{
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
            <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">  <!-- Disable auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail entirely -->
            <title></title> <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->
        
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:200,300,400,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
        
            <title></title> <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->
        
        </head>
        <style>
               
        
        </style>
        
        <body>
        
        <table style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:100%; text-align:center; border-spacing: 0px;" >
                 <table align="center" style="width:100%; max-width:600px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td ><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/cf30cf/fff.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%; max-width: 600px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class=""> 
                             <table style="width:100%; background:#525252; max-width:600px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
        
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="padding:15px; background:#0A0A0A;"> Move-in now to your dream home in City Center Plaza
     </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="padding:15px; background:#0A0A0A;"> BUTTON </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:15px; background:#0A0A0A;">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/cf30cf/fff.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%; max-width: 600px;"> </td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                           <td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:15px;">
                
        
                
        
                                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Did you know you can post HTML + CSS + JS embeds directly to stack overflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your code with this and see if this works:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; max-width:600px; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/cf30cf/fff.jpg" alt="" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block; width:100%; max-width: 600px;">
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Edit:

Here is 2 tutorials they helped me while creating HTML emails:

[Build an HTML Email Template From Scratch](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770)

[How to Code a Responsive Email from Scratch](https://litmus.com/community/learning/24-how-to-code-a-responsive-email-from-scratch)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by the other user, some of that space is coming from the the font size.

What I recommend is using either:

```
line-height: 0;
```

or

```
font-size: 0;
```

To remove that, and then put all text inside spans to put the size back up.

You also need to remove the padding from your cells,

```
tr, td {
    padding: 0; 
}
```

Complete changes required:

```
  tr, td {
    padding: 0; 
    line-height: 0; 
  }

  span {
    line-height: 1; 
  }
```

Plus wrap all text in spans.

Answer (score 0):

use "font-size: 0;"

and I think solve your problem

Example:-

```
<td style="font-size: 0;"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/cf30cf/fff.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%; max-width: 600px;"></td>
```

Comment: not working still there is some space, i tried to can image display type to different option but i still keep getting 1-2 pixels space.. This space goes out only if i use image as background -image that leads to other problems as i was to show full image as its ..

Comment: try "line-height: 0;"

Comment: use in your table tab - cellpadding="0"

Comment: and than use - <td style="line-height: 0;"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/cf30cf/fff.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%; max-width: 600px;"></td>